# Is this possible to apply a function to every fields of table (groupy by type)

Tags: oracle

I would like to replace every string are null by 'n' and every number by 0.

Is there a way to do that?

With a polymorphic table function I can select all the columns of a certain type but I can't modify the value of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with PTF also. You may modify columns in case you've set `pass_through` to `false` for the column in the `describe` method (to drop it) and copy it into `new_columns` parameter of the `describe`.

Below is the code:

> ```
> create package pkg_nvl as
>   /*Package to implement PTF*/
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   ;
>   
>   procedure fetch_rows;
> end pkg_nvl;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create package body pkg_nvl as
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   as
>     modif_cols dbms_tf.columns_new_t;
>     new_col_cnt pls_integer := 0;
>   begin
>     /*Mark input columns as used and as modifiable for subsequent row processing*/
>     for i in 1..tab.column.count loop
>       if tab.column(i).description.type in (
>         dbms_tf.type_number,
>         dbms_tf.type_varchar2
>       ) then
>         /*Modifiable*/
>         tab.column(i).pass_through := FALSE;
>         /*Used in the PTF context*/
>         tab.column(i).for_read := TRUE;
>         /* Propagate column to the modified*/
>         modif_cols(new_col_cnt) := tab.column(i).description;
>         new_col_cnt := new_col_cnt + 1;
>       end if;
>     end loop;
>     
>     /*Return the list of modified cols*/
>     return dbms_tf.describe_t(
>       new_columns => modif_cols
>     );
>   end;
>   
>   procedure fetch_rows
>   /*Process rowset and replace nulls*/
>   as
>     rowset dbms_tf.row_set_t;
>     num_rows pls_integer;
>     in_col_vc2 dbms_tf.tab_varchar2_t;
>     in_col_num dbms_tf.tab_number_t;
>     new_col_vc2 dbms_tf.tab_varchar2_t;
>     new_col_num dbms_tf.tab_number_t;
>   begin
>     /*Get rows*/
>     dbms_tf.get_row_set(
>       rowset => rowset,
>       row_count => num_rows
>     );
>     
>     
>     for col_num in 1..rowset.count() loop
>     /*Loop through the columns*/
>       for rn in 1..num_rows loop
>         /*Calculate new values in the same row*/
>         /*Get column by index and nvl the value for return column*/
>         if rowset(col_num).description.type = dbms_tf.type_number then
>           dbms_tf.get_col(
>             columnid => col_num,
>             collection => in_col_num
>           );
>           new_col_num(rn) := nvl(in_col_num(rn), 0);
>         elsif rowset(col_num).description.type = dbms_tf.type_varchar2 then
>           dbms_tf.get_col(
>             columnid => col_num,
>             collection => in_col_vc2
>           );
>           new_col_vc2(rn) := nvl(in_col_vc2(rn), 'n');
>         end if;
>       end loop;
>
>       /*Put the modified column to the result*/
>       if rowset(col_num).description.type = dbms_tf.type_number then
>         dbms_tf.put_col(
>           columnid => col_num,
>           collection => new_col_num
>         );
>       elsif rowset(col_num).description.type = dbms_tf.type_varchar2 then
>         dbms_tf.put_col(
>           columnid => col_num,
>           collection => new_col_vc2
>         );
>       end if;
>     end loop;
>
>   end;
> end pkg_nvl;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create function f_replace_nulls(tab in table)
> /*Function to replace nulls using PTF*/
> return table pipelined
> row polymorphic using pkg_nvl;
> /
> ```

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     1 as id, 'q' as val_vc2, 1 as val_num
>   from dual
>   union all
>   select
>     2 as id, '' as val_vc2, null as val_num
>   from dual
>   union all
>   select
>     3 as id, ' ' as val_vc2, 0 as val_num
>   from dual
> )
> select
>   id
>   , a.val_num
>   , a.val_vc2
>   , n.val_num as val_num_repl
>   , n.val_vc2 as val_vc2_repl
> from a
>   join f_replace_nulls(a) n
>   using(id)
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | VAL_NUM | VAL_VC2 | VAL_NUM_REPL | VAL_VC2_REPL
> -: | ------: | :------ | -----------: | :-----------
>  3 |       0 |         |            0 |             
>  2 |    null | null    |            0 | n           
>  1 |       1 | q       |            1 | q
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf82efcfee5d5fe8af75feb766eb9d2f)*

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` or `NVL` and list the columns you want to apply them to:

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1, 'n') AS col1,
       COALESCE(col2, 0)   AS col2,
       COALESCE(col3, 'n') AS col3
FROM   table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood the question, you actually want to modify table's contents. If that's so, you'll need dynamic SQL.

Here's an example; sample data first, with some numeric and character columns having `NULL` values:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID NAME           SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Little            100
         2                   200
         3 Foot                0
         4                     0
```

Procedure reads `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, checking desired data types (you can add some more, if you want), composes the `update` statement and executes it:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(1000);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select column_name, data_type
  5                  from user_tab_columns
  6                  where table_name = 'TEST'
  7                    and data_type in ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR2')
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      l_str := 'update test set ' ||
 11                cur_r.column_name || ' = nvl(' || cur_r.column_name ||', ''n'')';
 12      execute immediate l_str;
 13    end loop;
 14
 15    --
 16
 17    for cur_r in (select column_name, data_type
 18                  from user_tab_columns
 19                  where table_name = 'TEST'
 20                    and data_type in ('NUMBER')
 21                 )
 22    loop
 23      l_str := 'update test set ' ||
 24                cur_r.column_name || ' = nvl(' || cur_r.column_name ||', 0)';
 25      execute immediate l_str;
 26    end loop;
 27  end;
 28  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID NAME           SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Little            100
         2 n                 200
         3 Foot                0
         4 n                   0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table macro to intercept the columns and replace them with `nvl` if they're a `number` or `varchar2`:

```
create or replace function replace_nulls (
  tab dbms_tf.table_t
) 
  return clob sql_macro as
  stmt clob := 'select ';
begin
  for i in 1..tab.column.count loop
    if tab.column(i).description.type = dbms_tf.type_number
    then
      stmt := stmt || ' nvl ( ' || 
                tab.column(i).description.name || ', 0 ) ' ||
                tab.column(i).description.name || ',';
    elsif tab.column(i).description.type = dbms_tf.type_varchar2
    then 
      stmt := stmt || ' nvl ( ' || 
                tab.column(i).description.name || ', ''n'' ) ' ||
                tab.column(i).description.name || ',';
    else
      stmt := stmt || tab.column(i).description.name || ',';
    end if;
  end loop;
  
  stmt := rtrim ( stmt, ',' ) || ' from tab';
  
  return stmt;
end;
/

with a (
  aa1,aa2,aa3
) as (
  select 1, '2hhhh', sysdate from dual
  union all
  select null, null, null from dual
)
select * from replace_nulls(a);

       AA1 AA2   AA3              
---------- ----- -----------------
         1 2hhhh 27-JUN-2022 13:17
         0 n     <null>
```