# How to avoid to the change of the order of the columns in a polymorphic table function

Tags: oracle, plsql

this is the sequel of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741957/is-this-possible-to-apply-a-function-to-every-fields-of-table-groupy-by-type)

astentx give me a way with a polymorphic table function to apply nvl to every number and varchar2 colums.

But unfortunately, the order of the columns is changed.

The order is important because the result of the query is returned by a typed cursor (and after by pipelined function). therefore the order of the name of the fields must be same as the order in the record type used by cursor and the pipelined function.

I don't write the polymorphic table function code. You can find it in the link given in the beginning or [there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4ae5fdc4058b8333862704cb9bb4c031)

```
WITH
    a(aa1,aa2,aa3)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, '2hhhh', SYSDATE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL)
SELECT * from  f_replace_nulls(a) ;
```

> aa3, aa1, aa2 instead of aa1, aa2, aa3

Comment: Not making this an answer because it seems like there should be a better way, but it looks like maybe modified columns are appended after pass-through columns; so handling all columns - even if you don't actually change the data - [seems to fix it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=706712ac0c51812c8aa292303a24f849) for your example. Handing every possible data type seems like overkill though?

Comment: You can get & put every column, regardless of type, in the PTF to preserve the order. It's far easier to create a table macro that `nvl`s the columns as needed (I've added an example to your other question). Or list the columns in the order you want them in the final `select` clause!