# Is there a way to explicitly give a type in a common table expression?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is another sequel of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741957/is-this-possible-to-apply-a-function-to-every-fields-of-table-groupy-by-type):

I've to applied a polymorphic table function replacing all the null value of varchar2 by something.

In this example:

```
WITH
    a(aa1,aa2,aa3)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, '2', SYSDATE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (f_replace_nulls(a))
```

the type of aa2 is varchar2(1) because '2' is a varchar2(1).
if f_replace_nulls replace the null value by 'n/a' only 'n' will be given in dbfiddle and on my computer the following error occurs.

> [Error] Execution (2: 1): ORA-62576: target size(1) is smaller than source size(3) for column(AA2) in Put Columns

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9cc7fdecd979919e75e3af00f695c9b8)

To delete this problem I would like to explicitly mention that aa2 is a varchar2(5).

Or if there is another way to solve this problem, I would be glad to know.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Oracle 19

Answer (score 5):

You can cast a literal to a data type:

```
cast('2' as varchar2(5))
```

so:

```
WITH
    a(aa1,aa2,aa3)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, cast('2' as varchar2(5)), SYSDATE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (f_replace_nulls(a))
```

| AA3 | AA1 | AA2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27-JUN-22 | 1 | 2 |
| *null* | -1 | tn/a |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9701ea3481021df421e35b74edb06610)